# Can we have only VS Code instead of Visual studio professional version for connecting TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to evaluate VS Code instead of VS professional version for my work.

Can I use VS code with TFS for daily operations like?
Create work space?
Get latest source code? 
Code checkin?
Shelve set?
Code review request ?
etc?

Comment: Have you tried like... searching the VS Code extension marketplace? Or even Google? Trying to use what that gives you to perform the actions you describe on a test repo?

Comment: Most of that, except for the Code Review bits.

Answer (score 1):

As jessehouwing mentioned most of that are supporeted except for the Code Review bits.

You need to install [Visual Studio Team Services Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)

> **The following are the current features supported by the extension:**
>
> - Execute all basic version control actions such as add, delete,    rename, move, etc.
> - View local changes and history for your files
> - Include and Exclude changes (and move files between the two states)
> - Merge conflicts from updates
> - Check-in and update local files
> - Associate work items to check-ins
> - Provides an integrated TFVC Output window
> - Support for a TFS proxy
> - Supports workspaces created with Visual Studio (via tf.exe) or the    JetBrains IDEs and Eclipse (via the Team Explorer Everywhere Command
>     Line Client)
>
> To start using the TFVC features, [review the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#team-foundation-version-control-tfvc-support) and
>   check out the [TFVC Source Code Control for Visual Studio Code
>   video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be) which shows you how to configure and use the TFVC features.
>   The extension supports TFVC across Windows, macOS and Linux (with
>   separate configuration instructions for macOS and Linux; [see
>   video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNaEIVZfr0&feature=youtu.be)).
>
> If you’ve never used the extension before, we also have a
>   [walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk6LrzQX4P8&feature=youtu.be) to get you started.

***Source here : [Official Release of TFVC Support for Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/12/official-release-of-tfvc-support-for-visual-studio-code/)***

Comment: @Abhijeet Kedari Is that answered your question? any update?